# How to display map for the given coordinates(latitude & longitude) in windows phone 8

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8, maps

How to **display map for the given coordinates** on demand in windows phone 8?

Comment: Google Maps are Not Posibul in Windows phone

Comment: if not then bing maps also fine

Comment: Check this http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/IWP-55--Location-and-Mapping-for-Windows-Phone-8

Comment: you want to display that coordinate as center of map ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a map like this in xaml ..

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Width="480"/>
```

then in code write

```
            map.Center = new GeoCoordinate(26, 72);
            map.ZoomLevel = 15;
```